# create a div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

i'm trying to create a content in div when scrolling but the problem is when i scroll down it creates unlimted content and it goes for ever
i just want to create only one content in the div
i tryed to search to get the answer but all i found is the same thing unlimted divs when scrolling
here is my code :

```js
var messageGetter = $('#message1');
var firstChild = '<p class="message-content">I agree that your message is awesome!</p><div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div><div class="ball-right"></div>';
var secondChild = '<p class="message-content">I agree that your message is awesome!</p><div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div><div class="ball-left"></div>';


$(document).scroll(function(){
  var clientH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var memoY = messageGetter[0].getBoundingClientRect().y;
  var messageHight = messageGetter[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;

  if(clientH >= memoY){
    $('#message1').append(firstChild);
    
  }
});
```

```css
.message-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: calc(100% - 45%);
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #2E456D;
    width: 380px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font: 400 .9em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #2E456D;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.lower-container{
  height: 1400px;
  background-color: #00B4D8;
}

.virt-line{
  height: 1300px;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #CAF0F8;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px 50% 50px 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="lower-container">

  <div id="message1" class="message-right">
     <!-- <p class="message-content">I agree that your message is awesome!</p>
     <div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div>
     <div class="ball-right"></div> -->
     </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unset your event handler after job was done. Mark the handler:

```
$(document).on('scroll.ADD_CONTENT',function(){
   ....
```

And remove it after your div was added:

```
if(clientH >= memoY){
    $('#message1').append(firstChild);
    $(document).off('scroll.ADD_CONTENT');
    ....
```

Comment: sorry but what should i add instead of ADD_CONTENT ?

Comment: Leave it as is or replace with anything you like. It is just a label for an event<->handler jQuery tie, it is passed to the handler so it could apply some logic based on the label; or it lets us easily `off` the particular handler, without it it jQuery will `off` all the handlers for the event type.